# Comparing two values for equality using Regex

Tags: regex

I have the following set of data :

```
(Name=[Jane Doe]>[Jane Doe]),
(Job=[Temporary Employee]>[Full Time]),
(Address=[1 place]>[2 St.]),
(Title=[Account Manager]>[Account Manager])
```

I am trying to find out which name-value pairs have been modified. For example,

While Name value stayed the same "Jane Doe" to "Jane Doe", Job's value was changed from  "temporary employee" to "full time", Address' value was changed from "1 place" to "2 St.". Finally, title value remained the same.

All the comparisons will be done for values in [..] > [..]. I will also need what was changed, name, job, title and address.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT : Not sure why this was down voted. It is still a regex question where one needs to extract name, from-value and to-value pairs. Comparison will be done afterwards.

Comment: I suggest matching those entries that have not changed.

Comment: Can the changed values themselves contain square and angle brackets?

Comment: @ChrisHunt, no, they cannot contain square or angle brackets.

Comment: iterate and compare, regex has very little to do with your problem.

Comment: @npinti I don't know where to start.

Comment: You could start by looking at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx) tutorial. You can then use [this](http://regex101.com) website to test out what you are learning.

Comment: @webduvet, you are right. I just need to extract first [], second [] after > and whatever name is there before =

Answer (score 1):

You can only match the keys and values - regex will not compare them for you:

```
\(([^=]+)=\[([^]]+)\]>\[([^]]+)\]\)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/fN9tE9/1)

Comment: Good if the content doesn't contain brackets, I made a comment asking for that info.